# Elixir map_values in a map?

Tags: elixir

Ain't there a standard lib function that would allow to execute a `map_values` function over a `map`:

```elixir
Map.map_values(%{a: 30, b: 45}, fn v -> v*2 end) # = %{a: 60, b: 90}
```

The best way I found is:

```elixir
Enum.map(%{a: 30, b: 45}, fn {k, v} -> {k, map_fn(v)}) |> Enum.into(%{})
```

which I find pretty heavy since I use this quite often...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think so, but you can do it more concisely with [`Map.new/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#new/2):

```elixir
iex> Map.new(%{a: 30, b: 45}, fn {k, v} -> {k, v * 2} end)
%{a: 60, b: 90}
```

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to this is a *for comprehension* e.g

```
a = %{a: 30, b: 45}
    for {k, v} <- a, into: %{} do
      {k, v + 1}
    end
```

output :

```
%{a: 31, b: 46}
```

Through this way you are not creating an intermediate list, because `Enum.map` return a list and then you need to convert it to map.
Here the important part is the `into: %{}` because if you omit it, it will return you a list by default.

Answer (score 4):

While the already given answers are perfectly correct, for the sake of exhaustiveness I’d post another variant: there is [`Enum.into/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Enum.html#into/3) that also might be used **because `Map` implements [`Collectable`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Collectable.html)** protocol.

```rb
Enum.into(%{a: 30, b: 45}, %{}, fn {k, v} -> {k, v * 2} end)
#⇒ %{a: 60, b: 90}
```

Comment: Nice job! Enum is better than Map. It works on Elixir 1.1 too.